Error while loading conda entry point: conda-content-trust
I created a new python=3.12 environment using anaconda.
If I now want to install packages into this environment I get the following error message:
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-content-trust (DLL load failed while importing _rust: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.) Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): / Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json

...

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json

failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

I did not find a working solution so far. Would appreciate any help.
